# What is a word or phrase to describe when score is the most important part of testing and it does not reflect the real ability of the students?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

This is an issue in some fields, especially education. Because teachers are usually evaluated by the grades their students get in examinations and the number of excellent students in their class, teachers try their best to help their students get perfect marks but not by giving them quality lessons. They may give them answers during the exam or show them the questionnaire in advance. As for parents, they force their children to study as much as possible in order to get perfect marks.

In Vietnam, this issue is existing, but I am not sure that it is in other countries. I need a word or a phrase to talk about this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Teachers are evaluated only by student grades and try to improve the student grades without improving their teaching or students' learning.

This is a common argument topic specific to Education (happening in many countries) and this is often referred to as **teaching to the test**.

*When we teach to the test, we ignore the students' needs and focus on the wrong learning outcomes.*

Standardized tests are usually blamed as causing teachers and schools to develop curriculum and lesson plans that *teach to the test*.  Some of your examples are ways that teaching to the test has pressured teachers to do extreme things just to increase grade scores.

Answer (score 0):

A generally benign term for this is *grade inflation*, where good or excellent grades become the average for an entire class.  While grade inflation can be due to teachers giving out undeserving high marks, it can also be used to describe the situation at some elite schools (such as Harvard or Yale in the United States) where the majority of the students who attend, are already great students who normally achieve excellent scores.

Otherwise, there is no real term for the culture which allows this to happen, other than the usual one like *corruption, cronyism*, and *bribery*.   You might also call in an *anti-meritocracy* in which everyone succeeds regardless of whether they deserve it.